# Is there any software that displays a whole piece code for you?

Tags: java

Does anyone know if there is a software/program that will display a whole piece of code for you?

I've got a Java class with a long piece of code and I want to take a screenshot of it for my final year project report. The problem is i'm using a small screen laptop and can't get the whole code to display. I need to show the whole piece of code.

Is there such a software/program that exist? Or is there a method of displaying a whole piece of code?

Comment: Does printing the code and taking a photo count?

Comment: You could print the code as @Lekensteyn suggests, then use a color scanner to scan it back onto your machine.

Comment: I may be missing something, but can't you just print out the code instead of taking a screenshot? In Eclipse, this can be done by selecting `File`/`Print` from the menu.

Comment: What about zooming out and taking a screen shot of that?

Comment: @RonK You wouldn't be able to read any of the code.

Comment: Wait a minute, what about copy-paste? I mean, this is a report, so it's a document of some kind, what could possibly be stopping you from pasting the text of the code into that document?

Comment: 1. You may be trying to fit the code in one page. YOu can try smaller font but if code is lot longer than one page this won't work. 2. If you just need to have this code in the report you can try pasting into document, if formatting etc gets messed up you may need to try different things based on your word processor and your IDE.

Comment: Is there something wrong with handing in a print copy, or digital copy (i.e. the large piece of code)?

Comment: Editor/OS? What about printing to a PDF, and tranforming the PDF to an image? With gedit in Linux, you may print to pdf, ps and even svg. Or make several screenshots which you glue together with a graphics program?

Comment: @MrTeeth, what is the word processor (or other tool) you're using to produce your report?

Comment: Hi guys, I'm using Word 2007. Yes i'm trying to fit it all on page. What i want to do it start with an explanation of the code and I want the whole code to follow it.

BTW, thanks for the suggestion you guys gave me above. Printing it and scanning it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SnagIt (http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html).  It is a fancy screenshot taking tool.  You can point it to a "scrolling panel" (like in your IDE) and it will take a screenshot of that panel by essentially scrolling it and capturing the full contents.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.snagitguide.com/tag/snagit-scrolling-capture/

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll try this out.

I want to ask another question, do you know any programs that can auto-indent java code that has been indented properly?

Comment: Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ... any full featured IDE will have this feature.

Comment: i'm using eclipse...where can i find the function that will automatically indent your code. I mean...i've got code that hasn't been indented. I want to highlight the whole code and click on a button/function that will indent it for me.

Comment: ctrl-shift-f if you are in windows.  Or you can access it from the right click menu -> source -> format.  Or from the top menu: source -> format.

Answer (score 3):

The free open source editor, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download), provides colorized syntax highlighting of source code in a variety of languages, including Java.  If you're running Windows on your laptop, you could download it, paste in your code, menu select `Language, J, Java` to ensure correct colorization.  Select desired code snippet, right-click and choose `Plugin commands, Copy Text With Syntax Highlighting`.  Then you're ready to paste colorized, formatted code of any length into your word processor.

Answer (score 1):

In gedit, the Gnome-Editor, you can print to an SVG image. I you choose format portrait, and page size A1, you get much code on one page.